Stream storing a self-referencing future in rust
This is a simplified version of my code:
struct B;
impl B {
    pub async fn func(&self) {}
}

struct A<'a> {
    b: B,
    current: Option<std::pin::Pin<Box<dyn futures::Future<Output = ()> + 'a>>>,
}
impl<'a> futures::Stream for A<'a> {
    type Item = ();
    fn poll_next<'b: 'a>(
        self: std::pin::Pin<&'b mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> futures::task::Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let this: &'b mut A<'a> = self.get_mut();
        if let Some(future) = &mut this.current {
            future.as_mut().poll(cx).map(Some)
        } else {
            let future = this.b.func();
            this.current = Some(Box::pin(future));
            futures::task::Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

In reality A also stores a stream and polls it.
Currently my problem is that to store the future inside of A it needs to borrow A for 'a. But in this function self is borrowed for some lifetime 'b not connected to 'a. When I try to assert that b': 'a I get the reasonable error that that requirement is not in the Stream trait.
Is this not possible in safe rust?

Before anything else, try expressing what you want with async fn. It will make your life way easier.

what do you mean? I am implementing stream. Lets say i implemented all i wanted to do in a async fn. to turn that into a stream i would have to recall the function if it is not pending right now and store it inside of the stream to poll later. Which is the exact problem i am dealing with.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0f307f576561ede379453b4dbbe62675.

ah, ok i'll look into the implementation of unfold. can you put that link in an an answer?
